# Question regarding the proof of 'If $W_1\leqslant W_2$ then $W_2^\perp \leqslant W_1^\perp$'

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Let $W_1, W_2$ be subspaces in a finite-dimensional inner space $V$. Show:
>
> If $W_1\leqslant W_2$ then $W_2^\perp \leqslant W_1^\perp$.

#### My proof

Let $a,b \in W_2^\perp$ then $(\forall w\in W_2)(\langle a,w\rangle = 0)$ and $(\forall w\in W_2)(\langle b,w\rangle = 0)$.

Now consider $\lambda, \mu \in K$, then $\forall w \in W_2:$

$$\lambda\langle a,w\rangle + \mu\langle b,w\rangle = 0$$

Or euquivalent $\langle \lambda a+\mu b , w\rangle = 0$, which means $\lambda a+\mu b \in W_2^\perp$.

However, I don't seem to have used the property $W_1\leqslant W_2$? Is this reasoning valid, and where does it uses the *if* statement?

Comment: Where did you prove that $W_2^\perp \le W_1^\perp$?

Comment: Well, I proved that $W_2^\perp $ is closed under scalar multiplication and addition. That's a characterization of lineair subspaces right?

Comment: OK, but your "then" is $W_2^\perp \le W_1^\perp$. You didn't use the "if" because you didn't address then "then".

Comment: Do you mean, I have shown $W_2^\perp \leqslant V$, while I should be showing $W_2^\perp \leqslant W_1^\perp$? So, all that's left, is to show that $W_2^\perp \subseteq W_1^\perp$? (hmm, then the first part was not necessary, since $W_2^\perp$ is know to be a vector space)

Comment: Hmm, to obvious :) I see it clearly now. I would gladly accept your hint as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning is valid, but you should be aware of where your argument is going; that is, you have certainly shown that $W_2^\perp$ is closed under linear combination, but I don't think that is what you wanted to show. Here is my solution:

Suppose $x\in W_2^\perp$. Now if $w\in W_1$, by hypothesis, $w\in W_2$. But then $\langle x,w \rangle=0$. Yet, since $w\in W_1$, it follows that $x\in W_1^\perp$. Our choice of $x$ and $w$ was arbitrary; so, $W_2^\perp \leq W_1^\perp$.